# Time invariant system with sinc impulse

Tags: signal-processing, lti-system

[image]

Given said system, the impulse responses for the LTI systems \$H_1,H_2\$ are :
$$ h_{1}\left(\tau\right)=\frac{\sin\left(\omega_{1}\tau\right)}{\pi\tau}d\tau,h_{2}\left(\tau\right)=\frac{\sin\left(\omega_{2}\tau\right)}{\pi\tau}d $$
For \$T_1>2T_2 \,and \,\omega_1>\omega_2>0 \$
I need to find whether the whole system is time-invariant.

At first I used the fact that \$ z_{1}\left(t\right)=x\left(t\right)*h_{1}\left(t\right)=\int\limits _{-\infty}^{\infty}x\left(t-\tau\right)\frac{\sin\left(\omega_{1}\tau\right)}{\pi\tau}d\tau \$  because \$H_1\$ is an LTI system.
Using similar arguments I did the same for \$H_2\$.
In the end I came to the conclusion that:
$$ y\left(t\right)=\begin{cases}
\int\limits _{-\infty}^{\infty}x\left(t-\tau\right)\frac{\sin\left(\omega_{1}\tau\right)}{\pi\tau}d\tau & t\in\left[kT_{1}-T_{2},kT_{1}+T_{2}\right]\\
\int\limits _{-\infty}^{\infty}x\left(t-\tau\right)\frac{\sin\left(\omega_{2}\tau\right)}{\pi\tau}d\tau & else
\end{cases} $$

I tried putting a few functions such as \$x(t)=1,x(t)=t,x(t)=t^2 \$ and the integrals give me either \$ 1 \$ or \$0 \$ regardless of which \$\omega_1 \$ I put.

Putting \$ x(t)=t+\alpha \$ did not seem to matter either.
How do I approach this?

Answer (score 1):

If there is any 't' term multiplied in the output then the system will not be time-invariant.  Yet 't' can be a negative exponent numerator or a denominator, dt or trig. functions and many others.

Therefore functions like *x(t)=t times something* are not Time Invariant.

Comment: I think I understand. I used \$x(t)=2t\$.
Which gave me \$H(x(t))=0\$ but after doing \$ H(x(t+w))=2(t+w) \$ therefore the system is not time invariant.

Comment: Functions that decrease with time are expected. If "t is a multiplier then it is not stable (infinite output) and not time invariant. Functions like a decaying capacitor or inductor are common functions like \$H(t)=V ~e^{-t/RC}\$